# order divs in columns and prevent vertical free space

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Let's say, we have a website, which contains 5 columns: "Daily", "Weekly1", "Weekly2", "Monthly1", "Monthly2".

Now there is a script, which gets data from a MySQL Database in an unsorted sequence *(there is no way to sort by query I think)* and these Datasets ("cards" with specific height) should be shown in the dataset-corresponding column.

How to achieve this?

What I have is that the "cards" are placed in right column, but there is vertical blank space between the cards, if another card was placed in another column before.

Is there a way to achieve this in css or do I have to do a workaround in php or JavaScript?

**-edit-** Very minimal and not 100% working, but my actual test-file :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        body{
            width:100vh;
            background-color: darkolivegreen;
        }
        .spalte1{
            position:absolute;
            width: 20%;
            left: 0%;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: aqua;
            border: solid 1px;
        }

        .spalte2{
            position:absolute;
            left: 20%;
            width: 20%;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: solid 1px;
        }
        .spalte3{
            position:absolute;
            left: 40%;
            width: 20%;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: green;
            border: solid 1px;
        }
        .spalte4{
            position:absolute;
            left: 60%;
            width: 20%;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: gray;
            border: solid 1px;
        }
        .spalte5{
            position:absolute;
            left: 80%;
            width: 20%;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: deeppink;
            border: solid 1px;
        }

        .card{
            position: relative;
            background-color: bisque;
            border: solid 1px;
            height: 7vh;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="spalte1">spalte1</div>
<div class="spalte2">spalte2</div>
<div class="spalte3">spalte3</div>
<div class="spalte4">spalte4</div>
<div class="spalte5">spalte5</div>

<div class="spalte3 card">Karte1</div>
<div class="spalte1 card">Karte2</div>
<div class="spalte5 card">Karte3</div>
<div class="spalte4 card">Karte4</div>
<div class="spalte1 card">Karte5</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**-edit-** actually, i can't provide php, because i am rewriting my code and add the ordering on the page as a "feature". my actual code is just writing the cards in a table from left to right :)

sql:

```html
CREATE TABLE `tkarten` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Kartennummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Beschreibung` text NOT NULL,
  `erledigt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `inBearbeitung` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `wann` enum('daily','weekly','monthly','') NOT NULL,
  `fmn` enum('f','m','n') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `tkarten`
--

INSERT INTO `tkarten` (`id`, `Kartennummer`, `Beschreibung`, `erledigt`, `inBearbeitung`, `wann`, `fmn`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Karte 1 mach irgendwas hauptsache hier steht was', 0, 0, 'daily', 'm'),
(3, 2, 'Karte 2 macht auch irgendwas ... hauptsache hier steht was', 1, 0, 'weekly', 'n'),
(4, 3, 'Auch bei der dritten Karte haben wir arbeit', 0, 0, 'weekly', 'n'),
(5, 4, 'Die vierte Karte ist nicht so wichtig', 0, 0, 'monthly', 'm'),
(6, 5, 'Wir haben 5 voll... jetzt kann schon einer gegen sich selbst poker spielen', 0, 0, 'weekly', 'm'),
(7, 6, 'noch ne sechste Karte, weils so sch&ouml;n war.', 0, 0, 'monthly', 'f');
```

column "wann" = daily, weekly or monthly
column "fmn" = weekly1 or 2 and monthly 1 or 2

Comment: Should be do-able. Could you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: depends on how you've placed them now. in `<ul>´? in a table? in boostrap-columns?

Comment: Are we avoiding updating the mysql since you can't change that code? Because sorting in the query is usually the best way to go about it, an option probably exists to modify the query to suit your needs

Comment: please also provide php code that shows how you create those cards now. (including sql)

Comment: 1. the cards (the divs) have to live _inside_ the columns (the divs, which would be better a `ul`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for columns with cards in it:

```
//css

.columns {
  list-style-type: none;
  //width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px; 
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cards {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;

}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ededff;
  background: #ededed;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}


// html
<ul class="columns">

<li class="column">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="card">card1</li>
    <li class="card">card4</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="column">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="card">card2</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="column">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="card">card3</li>
    <li class="card">card5</li>
    <li class="card">card6</li>
  </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

This approach is easier than trying to position (absolute) several divs depending on it's content above some other divs...

For the php-part I can't give an answer yet, as there is no php-code yet to look at...

Comment: That is not the answer for my question (positioning the div's) but it open my eyes :) i only have to decide in my php code, which card in which column -> assign to multiple (each column) variables, and paste them in the html site inside the divs -.- too easy :)



but is there realy no way to say a "cell-div" to position the top most possible position under an other "cell-div" in a specific "column-div" ?!

Comment: There might be a (very complicated) way. This approach is much easier, cleaner, easier to maintain.

Comment: And yes, I didn't give the actual answer to your actual question. I gave an answer to your actual goal! [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)